# Why was my answer converted to a comment?

Tags: discussion

My Answer in Question [“Хотеть” or “хотеться”, “захотеть” or “захотеться”](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/11290/%D0%A5%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C-or-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C-or-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F). So I followed the link that was giveт to provide me some explanation. I read:

> Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question may be removed. This includes answers that are:
>
> - commentary on the question or other answers
> - asking another, different question
> - “thanks!” or “me too!” responses
> - exact duplicates of other answers
> - barely more than a link to an external site
> - not even a partial answer to the actual question

Well, my Answer is obviously not a comentary on the question, it is not asking another question, it's not "Thanks!", it is not a duplicate, it has no links and (the most important!) it gives a comprehensive answer to the Question.

So why my Answer was made to a comment and how a "real true" Answer to this question should look like?

Answer (score 1):

Well, to me your answer does look like an answer.  It would probably fit the "low quality" criteria - and I would add a comment stating somethine like "please avoid a simple one-line answer. We are looking for more expanded answers".

It's further likely that your answer would get downvotes, exactly because it's a one-liner whereas there is a clear opportunity to provide more details (as has been done in the accepted answer).  Hence, converting it into comment, in my opinion, saves you from receiving downvotes.

This may not answer your question of why it was converted - that's up to the moderator who did that to explain though - but I'm suggesting some possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

The reasons it was converted to a comment are following:

- It does not adds anything new to the answers that are already there.
- When answer is that short it most probably will lead for some discussions.
  As an extreme case think of an answer as short as just "Да". This could be valid but if you won't take some effort and elaborate it very likely that somebody will add a comment "Почему", somebody else will add comment "Нет" etc. This hardly will make the answer neither more valuable nor more readable.
- It is still a valuable note which would be nice to see right under the question.